# Dar formato a campo de una tabla SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008

Tengo la tabla de nombre Tabla con los campos:

```
indicador=>int
resultado=>nvarchar
```

al ejecutar un Select:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, Resultado FROM Tabla
```

el campo resultado tiene que tener el numero de decimales que el campo indicador tenga como valor puede ser 1, 2,3 y a la vez resultado debe tener formato de miles con coma por ejm: `3,512.89`

Como lo puedo lograr?

Comment: cuál es el tipo de datos exacto de campo1 y campo2?

Comment: @Lamak es de tipo float

Comment: En la pregunta decías que eran `decimal`, pero son todas las columnas `float`?

Comment: Cuando me preguntaste fui a revisar @Lamak ya corregí, disculpa

Comment: El formato es un tema del front-end, no debe de estar asociado con la tabla.

Comment: entonces qué pasa si campo1 tiene 3 decimales y campo2 tiene 1?, cuántos decimales debería tener `resultado`?

Comment: @Lamak campo1 y campo2 tienen la misma cantidad de decimales

Comment: Entonces se puede chequear solo campo1 ¿no?

Comment: bueno, tu pregunta es mucho más compleja de lo que parece. Obtener la cantidad de decimales de un `float` no es para nada algo simple. Más aún agregando el tema de separadores de miles, que sí o sí significa convertir el resultado a string, separarlo y agregarle una o más comas. No es algo recomendable de hacer a nivel de bases de datos

Comment: Lo siguiente ee lee en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) en relación `float`: _Tipos de datos numéricos y aproximados que se utilizan con datos numéricos de coma flotante. Los datos de coma flotante son aproximados; por tanto, no todos los valores del rango del tipo de datos se pueden representar con exactitud._ Esto no lo hace el tipo de datos más idoneo si se quiere una cantidad fija de decimales. Concuerdo con los comentarios de @LuisCazares y @Lamak(mas reciente)

Comment: En relación a lo que dice Lamak: ¿Cuál es la parte decimal de `1.23`? naturalmente dirías 23, pero esto es solo válido en el contexto del tipo `decimal`,  en un ` float` tal vez es : `22999999999999998`, entonces, ¿cual es la longitud de la parte decimal? Me parece que estas intentando una solución que nunca va a ser tal.

Comment: @Lamak tengo el numro de decimales en un campoMask si en este campo el valor es 3 van 3 decimales en resultado si el valor es 2 van dos decimales en resultado, puedes trabajar con esos valores

Comment: @Lamak el campo resultado es nvarchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes valerte del uso de la función `str()`, con lo que obtendrás cadenas de texto con el formato deseado.

La función recibe dos parámetros, la longitud todal de la cadena y la cantidad de posiciones decimales que dejará al formatear el número, por ejemplo:

```
with X as (
select *
  from (values (1, cast(1.25 as float), cast(1.25 as float), cast(2.5 as float))
             , (2, 1.25, 1.25, 2.5)
             , (3, 1.25, 1.25, 2.5)
       ) q1 (indicador, col1, col2, resultado)
)
select str(col1, 15, indicador), str(col2, 15, indicador), str(resultado, 15, indicador)
  from x;
```

Nos da la salida:

```
                                
--------------- --------------- ---------------
            1.3             1.3             2.5
           1.25            1.25            2.50
          1.250           1.250           2.500

(3 rows affected)
```